# Twitch api access token issues

Tags: python, twitch, twitch-api

currently im trying to work with the twitch api,

I successfully recieved my access token, however it says its wrong whenever i try to do anything else within the twitch api.

```
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer wejrwjre334',
'Client-Id': 'w9eii2',
}

params = (
('first', gamelimit),
)

a = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top', headers=headers,  params=params).content()
print(a)
```

I get this error:
  `File "C:/Users/myalt/OneDrive/Desktop/pythonProject1/main.py", line 26, in <module> a = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top', headers=headers, params=params).content() TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Which greets me with this page once i click the link: {"error":"Unauthorized","status":401,"message":"OAuth token is missing"}

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Try without the `()`!

Comment: Sorry which `()` should i be getting rid of?
In params i presume?

Comment: There's exactly one in your code.

Comment: Ah you mean at .content, thank you!

Comment: Woprks perfectly, thanks a ton